# A file named Butterfly7198.txt was found and It's boggling me

Tags: text-decoding

I happened to come across a file while changing images for a Toontown Rewritten's Context Pack I've been working on and I stumbled across this file marked

> Butterfly7198.txt

and upon clicking on it, I was greeted with the following prompt that reads

> "Hi. This isn't part of any grand story arc or anything. We're not using this as
>   some gimmick to announce some bold new feature. There's no big pot of gold at the end of this rainbow. We're looking for people with technical talent who want to help work on
>   Toontown Rewritten. You can discuss this file and its contents online if you wish. However, it IS meant to be solved alone, so please don't share answers or spoilers. Good luck. -Butterfly 7198"

Then I was greeted with a weird chain of letters and numbers on which I could only assume meant that this was encoded in some language I had no Idea about. The following goes
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I was wondering if anyone knew exactly what either language this was encoded with or whether or not there is someone out there that CAN help me decode this.

(Note: I tried using a Decoding website but from all the languages I checked, none of them were matching the language I was trying to find out. This has been boggling me ever since I started working on this 2 years ago.)

Comment: Googled the first bit and found a pastebin from 2017 with the same content: https://pastebin.com/H1BLwvLJ. Not that it helps, but interesting!

Comment: Googled the pastebin and found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/6blslp/need_to_decode_a_secret_message_by_devs/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/toontownrewritten/comments/6bqa8b/is_this_new/

Comment: Yes I know about it, Which is why I am coming to here asking for help because I dont understand encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be BASE64 encoded at least in parts. Putting it through a BASE64 decoder gives the text below which includes a few hints as to what this might be.

Yc@sDddlZddlZdZdZdefdYZdS(iNcCs:d}x-tdD]}tj||j}qW|S(Ntii(txranget_hashlibtsha256tdigest(tmthti((ssecret_message.pyt_ishasc   Cs#td}d}x_tdD]Q}|||t||t|7}||d@||||<||d@d|dS(NiR(ii(t_Robot__post_Robot__stk(tself((ssecret_message.pyt**init**s    cCs
|jdS(Ntd(tmove(R((ssecret_message.pytmoveDown scCs
|jdS(Ntl(R(R((ssecret_message.pytmoveLeft#scCs
|jdS(Ntr(R(R((ssecret_message.pyt  moveRight&scCs
|jdS(Ntu(R(R((ssecret_message.pytmoveUp)sc Csnt|tks0t|dks0|dkrd@rtS|j|7*||||f|*x&dD]}|jj|d|_qHWtS(NitdlruiRiRR R"i i@tdul!%()bBQvK6I%YaMYDkw)y*-V5nB-z)EE{)pz&/ZpJ $Y|9tg=v-^#xbH5W:`$RE]e~8'r;uU^R(JimTYaGbFev=E=3UrED9s/L(fIH+StudtlrtrlR(ii(ii(ii(ii(R&R%R'R((   ttypetstrRt
ValueErrorRtFalseRtreplacetTrue(   RRRtytdxtdytcxtcytbt((ssecret_message.pyR,s0,@$
cCsp|j\}}|jdkr4dd|d|fSt|j}|jdsVdSt|d tjdS(Nis7You are still %d left and %d above where you should be!ssCheater! Go solve it correctly!isQfvfXYn4NTzBGO8yj9r0NN94zFzTJas12P2/jMTsd3PQe62HyXtYvHhlk1qdltxJxigAqwZ3s9j+a8thAeYi3n6Mf7D58x+Dg8CXI/KQRG0zPhraYzLdg4bvMZIa9xc=(ii(RRRtendswithRt   _binasciit
a2b_base64(RRR/tk((ssecret_message.pytsolve:s( t__name__t
__module__RRRR!R#RR9(((ssecret_message.pyRs                   (thashlibRtbinasciiR6RRtobjectR(((ssecret_message.pyts

Comment: I see that in parts it is a BASE64 but also it looks as if it is also coded in a separate language, do you know what language it is off hand? If not, do you think its a bit more tricky than it looks?